# NextGen Gallery issues with Iframe plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, nextgen-gallery

I have tried few iframe based popup plugins with WordPress Nextgen gallery. It always generates a js error from frame_event_publisher.js file.

Is there anyway to prevent the loading of this file within another plugin?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I sm getting TypeError: this.find_parent(...) is undefined                                                                         this.find_parent(child).register_child(child.Frame_Event_Publisher);

Comment: I can confirm that this is still happening. To replicate, just open any admin page in an iframe and the error would appear.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is to forcibly dequeue the script. You'll have to add a condition to dequeue it only when needed since NextGEN probably needs this script to work.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_frame_event_publisher', 100 );
function dequeue_frame_event_publisher() {
    if ( is_admin() ) { // Add another condition to check if in an iframe.
        wp_dequeue_script( 'frame_event_publisher' );
    }
}
```